# Do you roll dice when a saving throw's result is an automatic success/failure?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

There are several features such as the [*bones of the earth*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bones-of-the-earth) spell which states:

> [...] If a pillar is created under a creature, that creature must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or be lifted by the pillar. **A creature can choose to fail the save**...

The Sorcerer's Careful Spell [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option which states:

> When you cast a spell that forces other creatures to make a saving throw, you can protect some of those creatures from the spell’s full force. [...] **A chosen creature automatically succeeds on its saving throw against the spell.**

And the [*compulsion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/compulsion) spell which states:

> [...] A target automatically succeeds on this saving throw if it can’t be charmed...

In cases like these does the target creature roll dice at all? Have they even made a saving throw?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No dice are rolled.

You are still making a saving throw, it's just that it works differently than your normal dice rolling.

This is because if you automatically succeed or fail on a roll, then there are no dice that need to be rolled.

The [DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#UsingAbilityScores) generally covers this idea on page 237:

> When a player wants to do something, it’s often appropriate to let the attempt succeed without a roll or a reference to the character’s ability scores. For example, a character doesn’t normally need to make a Dexterity check to walk across an empty room or a Charisma check to order a mug of ale. Only call for a roll if there is a meaningful consequence for failure.
>
> When deciding whether to use a roll, ask yourself two questions:
>
> - Is a task so easy and so free of conflict and stress that there should be no chance of failure?
> - Is a task so inappropriate or impossible — such as hitting the moon with an arrow — that it can’t work?
>
> If the answer to both of these questions is no, some kind of roll is appropriate.

Unless the saving throw has a qualifier for failing or succeeding by a certain value, then there is no reason to roll because the actual value doesn't matter - only success or failure matters and that's been predetermined.

Because of that, there is no opportunity to roll when the numerical result doesn't matter.

### If you really wanted?

I mean, I guess if you really wanted you could say that you roll, but whatever the result is, you get the predetermined result.

Comment: *Great* find on the DMG rule.

Comment: "Unless the saving throw has a qualifier for failing or succeeding by a certain value, then there is no reason to roll because the actual value doesn't matter" Now I wonder if there are "fail by 5 of more" saves that can have automatic failures as well...

Comment: @Medix2 I'd try and see if there are any with that qualifier that also fall under Dex/Str saves.

Comment: It might be worth, as a point of comparison, including Legendary Resistance in this answer.

Comment: "You are still making a saving throw, it's just that it works differently than your normal dice rolling." It may be helpful to support this claim given the question "[Does a creature that is immune to all outcomes (conditions, damage, etc.) of an effect still make a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147078)" or you could provide an answer there even

Answer (score 1):

[As NautArch said](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156204/do-you-roll-dice-when-a-saving-throws-result-is-an-automatic-success-failure/156205#156205), there is no need.

One thing I want to add for why it is not useful to roll is that there are no special numbers that will *magically* change the results of your roll.

When you do an attack, a natural 1 is an automatic failure (in the old days you would even roll a fumble die in this case) and a natural 20 (at times 19) is an automatic success and you do double the damages.

I think that's the main source of confusion. The saving throws do not offer any special cases, so rolling whatever will always have the same result, no matter what.