# How do Aura of Devotion and Beguiling Twist interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, immunities

At level 7, the Fey Wanderer ranger gets a feature called Beguiling Twist. The relevant part reads:

> Whenever you or a creature you can see within 120 feet of you succeeds on a saving throw against being charmed or frightened, you can use your reaction to force a different creature you can see within 120 feet of you to make a Wisdom saving throw against your spell save DC. (TCoE, p. 59)

Also at level 7, the Oath of Devotion paladin gets the Aura of Devotion, which says:

> You and friendly creatures within 10 feet of you can’t be charmed while you are conscious. (PHB, p. 86)

If a Fey Wanderer and a Devotion paladin are in the same party, and the paladin is targeted by an effect that would impose the charmed condition, does that trigger the ranger’s Beguiling Twist feature? Clearly one way or another the paladin won’t be charmed, but does its immunity function as an automatic success on the saving throw? Or should the paladin roll the saving throw even though it’s going to ignore the effect of a failure, just to determine whether or not the ranger’s ability will trigger?

Comment: Some related questions that you may find helpful/interesting: "[Do you roll dice when a saving throw's result is an automatic success/failure?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156204)" and "[Does a creature that is immune to all outcomes (conditions, damage, etc.) of an effect still make a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147078)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It depends / It is unclear

The following is a question about a similar situation:

- [Does a creature that is immune to all outcomes (conditions, damage, etc.) of an effect still make a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147078)

Notably it has a ["Yes" answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147081) and a ["No" answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147082), both high-scoring. The answer to that question is what matters here. If you do *not* make a saving throw against the Charmed condition then Beguiling Twist cannot activate as no saving throw was ever made. If you *do* make a saving throw against the Charmed condition, then Beguiling Twist would activate *if* the saving throw was succeeded on. Note that a creature could still *fail* the saving throw, they would simply be immune to the effects of that failure, well... at least until the Paladin got too far away or fell unconscious (probably).

---

And then we *also* have the following questions:

- [Does a Paladin's Aura of Courage prevent or suspend frightened effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122468)
- [What happens when a charmed target becomes unable to be charmed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124529)
- [While under a spell effect that's suspended, can you still make saving throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117083)
- [Does Calm Emotions still allow a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78670)
- [Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133379)

And these each have different answers taking different stances on similar topics. So basically... this seems to be an unclear (or at the very least, a not well agreed upon) part of the rules. It would seem then, that only your GM has the answers for this.